# What to give as value in check contact attributes in contact flow which is returning true or false from lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

Working on holiday check for the contact center so I have chosen **Dynamodb** as database for holiday list.
Including that **lambda** in contact flow so that if date matches it will run holiday message otherwise normal flow

Below is the lambda

```
try {
    var result = await dynamodb.query(params).promise()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.Items))
    if (result.Items.length === 1) {
        var dateItems = result.Items[0].date;
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Not holiday");
    return false;
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

which is successfully returning the true when date matches and false when date does not match according to the dynamodb holiday list.
But my question what should be used as value in Contact attributes(where namespace will be external) as shown in image [Contact Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni5FG.png)
Because lambda is returning true or false and in contact attributes i can use those conditions like **Equals to = true or false**

Answer (score 1):

The lambda needs to return an object with attributes, not a Boolean value. Something like ‘{isHoliday: true}’.
Then, you can use Check contact attribute block to branch based on the result, stored in ‘$.External.isHoliday’.
More details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/attribs-with-lambda.html